# Android Studio emulator missing hardware buttons

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I just installed Android Studio 1.0.2 and created a virtual device. When I run an app on the emulator, everything works fine except for the missing hardware buttons (home, menu, and back buttons). I tried to change the Android version of the AVD and the Skin but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone knows how to fix this problem please?

Comment: In Eclipse, when you create an emulator, you can specify if the device has hardware buttons. I `guess` it's the same in Android Studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Other answers are kind of deprecated now, because the Android emulator interface changed a little bit.

If you need to display hardware buttons on your Android emulator you have to followe these steps:

1. Open Android emulator devices
2. Click "Edit this AVD"
3. Select the first "Change" button beside the "hardware profile of the AVD"
4. Click "Edit device..." button
5. Uncheck this toggle.
6. Restart your emulator and you should see the hardware buttons now.

   [image]

Comment: This answer helped me. I edited a device in AVD Manager and accidentally thought I needed to check these. My buttons are back! :)

Comment: Annnnnnnnd the option is gone :/

Comment: Anyone figured this out for the latest version of Android Studio?   This option no longer exists.

Comment: Even when creating a new hardware profile and selecting this tick box, the buttons don't appear.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution worked for me:

- Open SDK Manager
- Go to Tools>Manage AVDs
- Edit your AVD and change the skin to "Skin with dynamic hardware controls"

Answer (score 7):

I could not get it to show the hardware controls. Simply clicking CMD+M (show menu command) does the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem with Android Studio 1.0.2, here is a workaround:

1. Navigate to your sdk folder e.g. (C:\Android\sdk) and open the AVD Manager from there (tools\lib\AVD Manager.exe) 
   **Note:** I had to copy AVD Manager.exe to (C:\Android\sdk) otherwise it will give you a "Failed to execute tools\android.bat error"
2. Create your virtual device with hardware skin
3. Close the AVD Manager

When you open the AVD Manager from Android Studio your newly created device will be listed.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the device simulator you use for AVD. In device settings uncheck "Has hardware keyboard".