# Hardware buttons not showing on Android Emulator (ALSO, App Switcher button (⌘O) from side panel not responding)

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

**I concisely described the problems in the screenshots**; read the below description **IF** needed.

1. The bottom bar on the Android Emulator showing the three hardware buttons (square/circle/triangle = Overview/Home/Back, respectively) suddenly disappeared. They were there the night before. Next morning, poof! Gone.
2. Ok, so the three buttons don't show on the emulator. So then I use the SIDE PANEL which ALSO shows the hardware buttons. HOWEVER, the square Overview button (⌘O) (aka the App Switcher button) in the side panel DOESN'T WORK. This means I can't open the app switcher now (where you see all apps running in the background).

So the hardware buttons on the screen have disappeared, and the side panel (as a backup) that also has these buttons -- well, ITS square Overbutton button (⌘O) doesn't work, so the side panel is not helping either.

I used the AVD manager to add a replica of the device, and it fixed the issues, but then after some days, the same issue occurs again. I'm using MacOS.

Any suggestions? Thanks much!

[IMAGE: App Switcher (Overview) button not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ9A0.png)

[IMAGE: Hardware buttons that look like these no longer showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdqLN.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;dr: in AVD, edit your device, click "Change" on your hardware profile, then un-select "Has hardware buttons"**

For me, this was all I was missing, and after a Cold Boot of my device the 3 hardware buttons showed on the bottom of the emulator again.

[Official Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#hpproperties) on hardware profile properties:

> #### Input: Has Hardware Buttons
>
> Select this option if your device has hardware navigation buttons.
> Deselect it if these buttons are implemented in software only. If you
> select this option, the buttons won’t appear on the screen. You can
> use the emulator side panel to "press" the buttons, in either case.

If you're using AVD through Android Studio, I would check out the answer to this question, it seems to have more updated screenshots than a lot of answers on here: [Android Studio emulator missing hardware buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660723/13986702)

*Android Studio version: 2022.3.1*