# Android emulator - Soft buttons showing beside the screen instead of on the screen

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-device-manager

I can't seem to get the soft back and home buttons to show at the bottom of the Android emulator, the way they would display in an actual phone or tablet. I have seen [answers to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660723/3935156), but I have applied them (the main one is unchecking "Has Hardware Buttons"):

[image]

And they do not work. I think it's because the soft buttons already display on the right-hand side of the emulator, so they don't need to show on the actual emulator screen:

[image]

How do I move the soft back and home buttons from the right side of the emulator, to the actual emulator screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to settings and then search for "system navigation", then select 3 button navigation:

[image]

[image]

[image]